# VBA code Paste Special Value in Visible cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want copy and Paste filtered Values in same sheet. However my code perfectly working while Paste filtered Values into another Sheet. but I want Paste it in Same Sheet.

My Code is:

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="23"

Range("B2:B" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Problem is While I am Pasting filtered Value in Same Sheet, it is Pasted in Hidden rows also.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. Do you want to paste after removing Filter ?

Comment: You need to fully qualify each Range/Cells/Row reference with a sheet object to have better control.

Comment: No, i don't want remove filter. Just i want paste value

Comment: So you're pasting into the middle of your filtered range?

Comment: I want Paste my Values only in my visible cells, which is my filtered cells. but above mention Code Past values invisible cells also @SJR